Getting error while connecting Tableau desktop with Snowflake server
I am trying to connect to the Snowflake server via Tableau desktop using the role RO.
While pulling a table from the Snowflake server I am getting the below error:

Unable to complete action Invalid table name value Error Code:
080ADB25 SQL compilation error: Object 'APEX_RAW_TKHIST1' does not
exist or not authorized.

Can someone please let me know if this is related to an access issue or what exactly is causing this error?
I tried to write a simple sql query and it throws this error.

It looks like an access issue. If you log into Snowsight using the same user as you’re using in this connection, can you query this table?

It's an access issue. Verify if the role RO has access on this table
SHOW GRANTS TO ROLE RO;
OR
SHOW GRANTS ON TABLE <DB_NAME.SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME>;

